# invalid queue name when creating SQS FIFO queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

When trying to create a FIFO SQS queue in Terraform as:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "my_queue" {
  name                       = "my_queue"
  visibility_timeout_seconds = 10
  message_retention_seconds  = 172800
  fifo_queue                 = true

  tags = merge(local.base_tags, { Name = "my_queue" })
}
```

the following error is thrown:

```
Error: invalid queue name: my_queue
```

Comment: It says that in the docs: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sqs_queue#name. Also, your answer is wrong, since it says `my_queue.queue` instead of `my_queue.fifo`.

Answer (score 10):

The solution was to set the queue name with the suffix `.fifo` like:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "my_queue" {
  name                       = "my_queue.fifo"
  visibility_timeout_seconds = 10
  message_retention_seconds  = 172800
  fifo_queue                 = true

  tags = merge(local.base_tags, { Name = "my_queue" })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your queue is a fifo queue

```
fifo_queue = true
```

Then you should always have the name suffixed with `.fifo` with `hashicorp/aws` provider.

Example of a FIFO queue

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "my_queue" {
  name         = "my_queue.fifo"
  fifo_queue   = true
}
```

If your queue is not a fifo queue, then the name need not have any suffix.

Example of a queue that's not FIFO

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "my_queue" {
  name         = "my_queue"
}
```